does data and instruction memory we see in the data path corresponds to the L1 Instruction and Data cache inside of the core?
In CPU data path there are blocks called data memory and instruction memory ? Are these blocks L1 Instruction and L1 data caches ?
For instance check figure 4.10 in this link.

We know that generally L1 and L2 caches are in the core as specified in this link .
Also in the below CPU layouts layouts we see L1 and L2 caches take place inside of the CPU together with pipeline stages and control units.

My question is does these data and instruction memory we see in the data path corresponds to the L1 Instruction and Data cache inside of the core?

No. The memories are just memories, generally. The implementation details aren't stated. However, there's no reason cache cannot be used. In fact, I used cache for both I and D memory in the R2000 from MIPS in the 1980s.

However, in the x86, P Pro and follow-on families, there is not separate I and D memories. It's von Neumann and any cache serves both spaces. Since the diagram is about a CPU with separate memory spaces, the diagram is not reflective of the x86 or its L1 (etc) caches. Different system/memory designs.

I see, thank you!

@periblepsis: MIPS systems are normally von neumann as well (but unlike x86, I-cache isn't required to be coherent with data load/store: you have to manually invalidate cache before jumping to a buffer you JIT some new machine code into).  Split L1i/L1d caches allow efficient pipelining without conflict between instruction-fetch and data load/store, which is why all modern designs do that, including all modern x86.  (e.g. https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/ is a good deep-dive on the first generation of Intel's still-current Sandybridge-family.)

See also Separate instruction and data memory , and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture (split L1 caches in front of unified L2 / L3 and memory).

@PeterCordes Check out the R2000, which is what I used. Separate I and D cache. I also worked at Intel on the BX chipset. This would be circa year 1998-ish, around the PPro/P II period. I'm slightly comfortable with front side and back side buses and the internal layout of the ROB, registration stations, and the retire unit.

@periblepsis: Yes, split I/D caches in front of unified L2 and memory is called Modified Harvard, and is what basically everything uses these days because of the performance advantages. (Or huge power/area advantages vs. a double-sized unified L1 with more read and write ports.)  PPro also uses split L1i / L1d caches inside the CPU itself, 8K each. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_Pro). L2 was on-package but not yet on the same die until PII or PIII. Regardless, external busses would only deal with physical addresses.

@periblepsis: You could design a Harvard-architecture MIPS CPU, but I don't think R2000 had separate external busses for instruction memory and data memory.  And I doubt the TLB could translate the same address differently for code-fetch vs. data load/store.  So I don't think it's accurate to say that instruction memory is separate from data memory in R2000, or any real-world MIPS server/desktop; maybe some embedded designs that only run code from ROM?

@PeterCordes Are you saying I don't know what I actually saw and did? This was a custom board for the PC system and I spent 2 days at MIPS on a personal 1:1 with Dr. Hennessey back then getting up to speed. Feel free, I guess. We end this here.

@periblepsis: It wasn't clear from your first comment you had actually designed an R2000 board; I thought you were talking about just using a MIPS workstation or something.  Did you disable paging for that, or just have your page tables set up so it was a non-problem for your use-case?  Or since your memories weren't 4GiB each, you used non-overlapping addresses for I and D?  And you're saying you used its I-cache and D-cache external interfaces as the only memory?  Neat hack to build a Harvard MIPS, but that's not the normal setup used in e.g. SGI workstations.

Anyway, mostly I was trying to make the point that a normal MIPS is a Modified Harvard machine, with split L1i / L1d, but with one address-space same as x86.  (e.g. for TLB entries).  I think your first 2 comments make a stronger distinction than is warranted, and would be misleading to future readers.

@PeterCordes It sounds to me as though you are calling me a liar. That's where things end between us. If you want, go back and review the R2000 design, correct yourself and apologize. But I'm not going to be told I'm lying nor engage in slippery excuses.

@periblepsis: Sorry for earlier misunderstandings, but I don't see how you're getting that accusation from my last 2 comments. IDK what claims you're actually making, and I'm surprised to hear you're still disagreeing with what I'm saying.  I don't know everything about R2000, but I do know that Unix workstations used it, and Unix systems have mmap with von-neumann semantics.  In my previous comment, I was hypothesizing about how it might be possible to build a system with separate I and D memories using the cache busses, as long as you don't need them to have separate address-spaces.

@periblepsis: Wikipedia says R2000 has separate code and data caches, something we both agree on.  It also talks about external chips to buffer writes "to main memory DRAM", implying (but not explicitly saying) that there's just one unified main memory (in a normal system configuration using DRAM for main memory, unlike your board where you used just the cache interfaces as separate I and D memories if I understand you correctly).  I had earlier conflated separate memories with separate address-spaces, but you never claimed the same addr for lw/sw could access different cells than code-fetch.

@PeterCordes Read the wiki. It's nor perfect but it does make the right inferences. I was working at the hardware level and writing my own operating system for it. Given separate, physical I & D bus paths and given the insane clock rates, Harvard was the only viable choice. I consider myself well informed at that level. Linux wasn't a twinkle in someone's eye at the time. I really am not enjoying this. So the last word is yours.

@PeterCordes Read what I wrote, originally. I made only an accurate and modest, prosaic claim. You went on a tangent. Nothing I said was wrong in any detail. We really are done.

@periblepsis: I'm done debating MIPS R2000 separate memories vs. just separate caches.  But your second comment makes an inaccurate claim about x86, that any cache serves both spaces.  Intel has used split L1i/L1d caches since PPro, a claim backed up by wikipedia, https://agner.org/optimize/, https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/P6.html, and for Core 2 through Sandybridge for example, https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/10/.  (Stores snoop the pipeline to detect SMC: Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code)
